# Same object files with different performance

Tags: file, object, gcc, arm

I am using an ARM cortex A9 platfrom to measure the performance of some algorithms. More specifically i measure the execution time of one algorithm using the `clock()` function (time.h). I use the latter function right before calling my algorithm and right after the algorithm returns.

```
 .... 
 ....
 ....
 start=clock(); 
 alg();
 end=clock(); 
 ...
 ...
 ...
```

Then I compile the code with exactly the same options and i produce two different object files. The first one is named n and the second one nn. On the ARM platform i run my code in one core. All the other tasks'affinity is set to the other cores. Object file n returns 0,12sec while Object file nn returns 0.1sec. I compared the two binaries files and they don't differences. I noticed that if I give a name to the object file larger than 1 letter then I always have less execution time for my algorithm. Moreover if I run the n.c file and then rename it and run it again I will also get different performance numbers.

Could you please give me some ideas why something like this happens? Thanks in advance

P.S.1: I am using gcc 4.8.1 cross compiler.

P.S.2: I compile my code with 
        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mthumb -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfloat-   abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -Ofast code.c -o n

Comment: It is much better to show the implementation of `alg()`.  Does it use memory heavily, is it computational only, does it use globals, pthreads, etc.  I think your question is very **broad** as it is.

Comment: alg() is calculating the transpose of a big array (19MB) using tilling techniques. So 95% of alg() is pure memory accesses. I am not using globals or pthreads!!

Comment: Are the object files 'n' and 'nn' in the same binary?  You obviously have a cache and/or memory issue.  L2 will compete with code as they are usually unified.  Also, generated and examine a 'map' file (`gcc -Wl,-map,/path/to/map`).  If the binary offset and or sizes of 'n' vs 'nn' differ, it is a clue as to where the cache collision may occur.